# Parameterized MDX query in SSRS 2008 with Multiple Rank Columns

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, mdx, rank

I'm struggling to figure this one out and was hoping someone out there might be able to help.

I have an SSRS (2008) report that connects directly to an SSAS OLAP Cube.  I have 5 different columns, each showing a different measure, broken out by the "Manager" dimension.  I also have parametrized dropdowns in SSRS that filter the data based on various things.

Here's the code that got me to this point:

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY{
[Measures].[Metric A]
,[Measures].[Metric B]
,[Measures].[TMetric C]
,[Measures].[Metric D]
,[Measures].[Metric E]
 } ON COLUMNS
,NON EMPTY{
 ([Ops Hierarchy].[Manager].[Manager].ALLMEMBERS )
 } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS

 FROM
 (
     SELECT
     (
         STRTOSET(@CompleteDateCalendar, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS
         FROM
         ( 
             SELECT
             (
             STRTOSET(@City, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS

             FROM
             (
                 SELECT
                 (
                     STRTOSET(@Region, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS
                     FROM
                     (
                        SELECT
                        (
                        STRTOSET(@Country, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS

                        FROM
                        [CUBE]
                     )
                 )
             )
         )

 WHERE
 (
 IIF( STRTOSET(@Country, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1, STRTOSET(@Country, CONSTRAINED)
 , [Ops Hierarchy].[Division Name].currentmember )
 , IIF( STRTOSET(@Region, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1, STRTOSET(@Region, CONSTRAINED)
 , [Ops Hierarchy].[Region Name].currentmember )
 , IIF( STRTOSET(@City, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1, STRTOSET(@City, CONSTRAINED)
 , [Ops Hierarchy].[System Name].currentmember )
 , IIF( STRTOSET(@CompleteDateCalendar, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1, STRTOSET(@CompleteDateCalendar, CONSTRAINED)
 , [CompleteDate].[Calendar].currentmember )
 )
  CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

And of course, SSRS automagically created the corresponding dropdowns for each @parameter.

Now, here's where I need help:

I have a new requirement to add a "Rank" column for each metric.  So, for example, next to the "Metric A" column, there will be another column called "Metric A Rank" that ranks the manager on that row against the other managers that are showing on the report (based on the parameters selected in the dropdowns).

Now, I know that I can add:

```
WITH

SET [OrderedSet1] AS ORDER(FILTER([Ops Hierarchy].[Manager].MEMBERS,[Measures].[Metric A] <> NULL),[Measures].[Metric A],BASC)
MEMBER [Measures].[Metric A Rank] AS RANK([Ops Hierarchy].[Manager].CurrentMember,[OrderedSet1])

SET [OrderedSet2] AS ORDER(FILTER([Ops Hierarchy].[Manager].MEMBERS,[Measures].[Metric B] <> NULL),[Measures].[Metric B],BASC)
MEMBER [Measures].[Metric B Rank] AS RANK([Ops Hierarchy].[Manager].CurrentMember,[OrderedSet2])
```

etc, to the top of the MDX query, and then reference [Measures].[Metric A Rank] and [Measures].[Metric B Rank] in my select statement.

What I don't know how to do is filter the sets with the SSRS dropdowns so that I'm ranking against only what is showing on the report.

So for example, if someone has Country="USA", Region = "South", City = "Atlanta" and CompleteDate = "Jan 2012" selected in SSRS, and I rank Metric A against OrderedSet1, then I only want to show how each manager ranks against other managers in Atlanta for Jan 2012.

**How do I "parameterize" the sets in the WITH clause using the SSRS dropdowns so that I'm only ranking against the subset that the user has selected?**

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

in Set declaration you can use

```
SET [OrderedSet1] AS ORDER(FILTER([Ops Hierarchy].[Manager].MEMBERS*
[Ops Hierarchy].[System Name].currentmember
,[Measures].[Metric A] <> NULL),[Measures].[Metric A],BASC)
```